# エラーコードの改善が分かりません。SyntaxError: invalid character in identifier

Tags: python, numpy

下記のコードを実行するとエラーが出るのですが、改善箇所が分かりません。

```
Dis_sample = []
for _ in range(10):
    PP = np.random.choice(P_sample_all.shape[0], 2, replace=False)
    PP_sample.append(PP)
   
　　Dis = np.sqrt((P_sample_all[PP[0], 0] - P_sample_all[PP[1], 0])**2+
                (P_sample_all[PP[0], 1] - P_sample_all[PP[1], 1])**2+
                (P_sample_all[PP[0], 2] - P_sample_all[PP[1], 2])**2)
    Dis_sample.append(Dis)
```

これがエラーです。

```
 Dis = np.sqrt((P_sample_all[PP[0], 0] - P_sample_all[PP[1], 0])**2+
   ^   
SyntaxError: invalid character in identifier
```

追記
エラー部分をfor文の外で実行すると、正常に作動します。

Answer (score 1):

その行のインデントに全角空白が使われています。
半角空白に修正してください。

---

コメント対応：

そう言えば、エラーの行の直前の空白行が半角空白3桁になっていて、他の行と違っているようですが、それは影響あるでしょうか？試しに揃えてみてください。

Comment: ^の位置がエラー表示からずれていました。現在の通りです。また空白をすべてなくしてもう一度コードを実行してみたのですが、同じエラーが表示されてしまします。

Comment: 実行環境は何でやっていますか？ Windows10の素の64bit Python 3.9.1のインタプリタでは全角空白を半角空白に変更すれば、その行のエラーは無くなりました。ちなみにファイルにして実行していて、修正した内容をファイルに反映していないとかでは？

Comment: anacondaで提供されているjupyter　notebookで実行しています。windows10の64ビット版です。ファイルではなく、コードをそのまま実行しています

Comment: 別のところからの助言で解決されました。改行時にDisの部分にエラーが発生しており、改行をやり直しましたら正常に作動いたしました。お手数をおかけしました。ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 0):

改行時に前の文とつながりが生まれており、Disを定義した部分が変数定義として反映されていなかったのが問題でした。

前の文との間にある空白行を消すことで改善されました。そのあと再び改行してもエラーは出なくなりました。

Comment: それは最初の質問のエラーに隠されていた、別のエラーだと思われます。例えばこんな記事を参考にソースコードのチェック機能を導入すればtypoレベルの簡単なエラーはそれらで防げるのでは？ [Jupyter notebookでPEP8を使う](https://qiita.com/hiroyuki827/items/1367f6d2aefc2452fd26), [Using Pylint in Ipython (Jupyter-Notebook)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50358327/9014308)