# SyntaxError: invalid character in identifier を解決したい

Tags: python

この構文は間違いないと思いますが、`else:` の部分でタイトルのようなSyntaxError: invalid character in identifier のエラーが出てしまいます。

どこを間違えているのか教えていただけないでしょうか。

```
for i in range(v):
    if i%2 == 0:
       print("i=",i)
　  else:
       print(" ")
```

Answer (score 1):

よくある間違いですね。

```
　  else:
```

この行の先頭の文字が全角空白になっています。
半角空白2桁に修正すれば良いでしょう。

---

ちなみにこのサイトのトップで検索の欄にエラーメッセージを入力して検索すれば以下のような同様の記事が見つかりますので、今後はそれも試してみてください。

[エラーの原因を教えてください SyntaxError: invalid character in identifier](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/77638/26370)
[SyntaxError: invalid character in identifier を解決したいです](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/74091/26370)
[エラーコードの改善が分かりません。SyntaxError: invalid character in identifier](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/73067/26370)

Answer (score 1):

`else` の行に全角の空白文字が含まれています。

**エディタで空白文字を表示した例:**

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]